# PHP 7.4.21 Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, mamp

I'm trying to upload files using MAMP on mac but it just get me to the upload.php page and does nothing. I checked my error log an i saw this warning *"Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"*. How can i fix this, thanks in advance for any answers.

**Upload.php:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

    // Looping all files
    for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileExt = explode(".", $filename);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
    $fileNameNew = $filename.'.'.$fileActualExt;
 
  
    // Upload file
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],'videos/'.$fileNameNew);
    print_r("Bestanden zijn verstuurd!");
    }
}
```

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
   
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try Simply try count($FILES)?

Comment: No i didn't but i found the solution I had to change the input file name="file" to name="file[]" and after that it works.